# Bigquery - Using Search Function to Identify Multiple Names

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to search against a table which has the columns:

1. ID
2. Full_Name
3. Address

I have a list of full names I want to use in the query. I can run a single search query and return values where the search result = true...

```
SELECT
  ID,
  Full_Name,
  Address,
  `NAME_MATCH`
FROM (
    SELECT
      ID,
      Full_Name
      Address,
      SEARCH (`Full_Name`,'John Doe') as `NAME_MATCH`
  FROM `mytable`
) AS t
WHERE t.`NAME_MATCH` = true;
```

How do I run multiple 'John Doe' values? I have hundreds of names to search. They are in another table, say t2, in a column called `INDIVIDUAL_NAME'.

The results have been quite good if I use SEARCH. If I should use another function? Would it be better than the SEARCH function?

Thanks!

I have not been able to write a script to utilise the search function using multiple search queries.

Comment: Anyone? Would really value the advice.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I endedup using **REGEX_CONTAINS**.

Check if the solution bellow helps you

```
  WITH table1 AS (    
  SELECT 1 ID, 'Olive Yew' Full_Name, 'Address 1' Address
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 ID, 'Aida Bugg' Full_Name, 'Address 2' Address
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 ID, 'Maureen Biologist' Full_Name, 'Address 3' Address
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 ID, 'Peg Legge' Full_Name, 'Address 4' Address        
),

table2 as (
  SELECT  Full_Name FROM table1 WHERE id < 3
)


  SELECT
  ID,
  Full_Name,
  Address,
  NAME_MATCH
FROM 
  (
    SELECT t1.*,REGEXP_CONTAINS( upper(t1.Full_Name), upper(t2.Full_Name)) NAME_MATCH
    FROM table1 t1, table2 t2 
  )
WHERE NAME_MATCH
```

Ref: [REGEXP_CONTAINS GCP Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_contains)